# Querying by a field with type 'reference' in Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called 'categories' containing a single document with ID: 5gF5FqRPvdroRF8isOwd.

I have another collection called 'tickets'. Each ticket has a reference field which assigns the ticket to a particular category.

The field in the tickets collection is called 'category' and has a field type of `reference`.

In the code below, `categoryDocId` is the document ID of the category I want to query by.

```
const categoryDocID = `5gF5FqRPvdroRF8isOwd`;

const files = await firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('tickets')
  .where('category', '==', categoryDocID)
  .get();
```

Why does `files.length` return 0?

For testing, I changed the `category` field type to string, and set it to the category ID instead of a direct reference. This correctly returned tickets assigned to the category, which leads me to believe it's something about how I'm querying a `reference` field.

Comment: This answer seems to indicate that such a query is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937202/query-a-reference-field-in-firestore-document. I don't see how your code is different, so it should work the same as there.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

As you will read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) in the doc, the Reference Data Type is used to store [DocumentReferences](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference).

If you want to use it in a query, you cannot use a simple string, neither the UID of the document (i.e. `'5gF5FqRPvdroRF8isOwd'`), nor the string value that is stored in the field (i.e. `'/categories/5gF5FqRPvdroRF8isOwd'`).

You have to build a DocumentReference and use it in your query, as follows:

##### JS SDK V9

```
import { doc, query, collection, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const categoryDocRef = doc(db, "categories", "5gF5FqRPvdroRF8isOwd");

const q = query(
  collection(db, "tickets"),
  where("category", "==", categoryDocRef)
);

const files = await getDocs(q);   // !! files is a QuerySnapshot
```

##### JS SDK V8

```
const categoryDocRef = firebase.firestore()
   .collection('categories')
   .doc('5gF5FqRPvdroRF8isOwd');

const files = await firebase   // !! files is a QuerySnapshot
  .firestore()
  .collection('tickets')
  .where('category', '==', categoryDocRef)
  .get();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Renaud. I just confirmed this in a jsbin: https://jsbin.com/qowelew/4/edit?js,console. I'm not sure why [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/47937202) is using strings for references.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the confirmation, Frank

Comment: At the moment, using `reference` as type is almost useless. Only thing it adds to you is that you don't make mistakes like referencing a document that doesn't exist. They have talked about this on their Google Channel:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Elg2zDVIcLo

Comment: Hi , any suggestions on how to query on the map field? I've my collection document structure like this https://ibb.co/wKvSmFb

Comment: Any update on this? Would just make sense to be able to query by reference id.

Comment: @ChrisChross AFAIK nothing has changed since the answer was written.

Comment: this means that it's not possible to use the firestore UI to query the document by a reference-type field, am I right?

Comment: You can use the reference type to get a document from a collection. See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

### With Firebase Version 9 (Dec, 2021 Update):

You must make a **document reference** with **"categories/5gF5FqRPvdroRF8isOwdand"** then use it in your query:

```js
import { doc, query, collection, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const categoryDocRef = doc(db, "5gF5FqRPvdroRF8isOwd");

const q = query(
  collection(db, "tickets"),
  where("category", "==", categoryDocRef)
);

const ticketDocsSnap = await getDocs(q);
```

Comment: This was helpful for me. Thank you.

Believe you need to specify from which collection you intend to search for the ref: `const categoryDocRef = doc(db, '<COLLECTION>', ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I use reference type to query a collection (node.js + typescript):

```
let myCollectionADocument = await admin.firestore().collection("collection_a").doc("documentId").get();
let myCollectionB = await admin.firestore().collection("collection_b").where("collection_a_id", "==", myCollectionADocument.ref).get();
```

Comment: Please answer my queries in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68442405/how-to-set-where-condition-on-array-of-reference-selection-in-flutter-using-clou.
thanks in advance