# Querying an Exact Object using Where in FireBase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a structure like this

```
{
  comments: {
   ...anything here
  },
  flags: {
   flag1: true,
   flag2: false
  }
}
```

is there a way to query an exact object in firebase?

I've tried to use it like this.

```
const documents = await adminSdk.firestore()
   .collection('posts')
   .where('flags', '===', { flag1: true, flag2: false })
   .get();


console.log(documents.data());
```

but it returns **nothing**.

is there a way that I messed up or it's just out of scope for **Firebase** to do it like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Comment: Not even close, as its for a multiple query more like an OR query.

this one's more like an exact query of something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to an object property just like in javascript with the dot.

```
.where('flags.flag1', '==', true)
.where('flags.flag2', '==', true)
```

Comment: Thanks, but on the side note, how can you query a reference using where? @firebaser

Comment: @Reyn have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140913/querying-by-a-field-with-type-reference-in-firestore/53141199#53141199

Answer (score 0):

The operator you are using is not on the docs (firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

```
const documents = (await adminSdk.firestore()
   .collection('posts')
   .where('flags', '==', { flag1: true, flag2: false })
   .get()).docs.map(doc => doc.data());
```

should give you an array of posts