# How to filter Firestore specific collection's doc data by its reference value with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections `section1` and `section2`. Collection `section2` has a field `doc_id`, it's a `reference` type field and represents a relationship between `section1` and `seciton2`.

[image]

I want to retrieve data from `section2` for given value for `doc_id` field. check the sample codes it works fine when I filter data with any other field such as `district`. But it does not work with reference field type fields

This gives expected result

```
const getDocumentData = async () => {
    const q = query(
      collection(db, "section2"),
      where("district", "==", "dhanbad")
    );

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
```

Code works but I don't get the values. It returns null.

```
   const getDocumentData = async () => {
    const q = query(
      collection(db, "section2"),
      where("doc_id", "==", "H0ovBXfrwen32Xb4Ig9A")
    );

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
```

Comment: Can you show a code example that *doesn't* work, with a hardcoded value for the condition on the reference field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the screenshot, a document reference field is equivalent to the entire reference to that document (from the root of the database). So you can't just specify the document ID, but have to specify an actual document reference.

```
const docRef = doc(db, "section1", "H0ovBXfrwen32Xb4Ig9A");
where("doc_id", "==", docRef)
```

Also see Renaud's answer to: [Querying by a field with type 'reference' in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140913/querying-by-a-field-with-type-reference-in-firestore)